# Trying to close c++ program at certain time returns value's (that i don't want)

Tags: c++

Running the code returns no errors, the problem is when I try to exit the program.
Simply, when i use the exit, return or abort functions, i get this (picture below)
[image]

see code below

```
//First 2 libs handle info exchange
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
main(){

    string username;
    cout << "Please enter a general use handel (\"username\")\n";
    cin >> username;

    fstream blockUsername;

    blockUsername.open("Player_Data/username.txt", ios::out); //out is for writing, in is for reading
    blockUsername << username;  
    blockUsername.close();

    return 0;

}
```

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked, but I have not succeeded in fixing my code with those.
What I want is for the program to close with no exit values, even though I know that they are useful.

PS: It very well could be something to do with my code editor (Dev C++), or my compiler which i broke and had to fix recently.

Also side note how would i go about removing that address at the top of the terminal (and potentially replacing it with something else)?

Comment: Those two last lines are printed by the IDE you use, not your program. If you run it standalone outside the IDE, you won't see them.

Comment: As for the title, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792683/529282

Comment: Thank you very much @IgorTandetnik !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are printed by your IDE....if u execute the .exe output of this code...the console would just disappear after program exits and it would not be shown

Peace

Comment: It is also usually an option to turn it off. Look through the IDE options.

Comment: Yeah mostly it is for debugging options....if program doesn't return 0 it means that it didn't executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

try using `return 0;` wherever you want to exit, it's okay to have more than one `return 0;` in your code or to simply put it after an `if` statement.